# Error with group by statement?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm getting the following error when I run this code. please help me out.

```
SELECT store, COUNT(DISTINCT saledate), CountNov, CountDec, SumNov, SumDec, (SumNov/CountNov) AS NovAvgRvn, (SumDec/CountDec) AS DecAvgRvn FROM 
(
SELECT store, saledate, 
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '11' THEN amt END) IS NULL THEN 0 
ELSE SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '11' THEN amt END)
END AS SumNov, 
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN amt END) IS NULL THEN 0 
ELSE SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN amt END)
END AS SumDec, 
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '11' THEN saledate END) IS NULL THEN 0 
ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '11' THEN saledate END)
END AS CountNov, 
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN saledate END) IS NULL THEN 0 
ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN saledate END)
END AS CountDec 
FROM trnsact 
WHERE stype = 'p' 
GROUP BY store, saledate  
) AS T1 
WHERE CountDec > 0 AND CountNov > 0 
GROUP BY store 
ORDER BY store;
```

Error: 
Error Code - 3504 
Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 3504] [SQLState HY000] Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a nested query for this?

```
SELECT store, COUNT(DISTINCT saledate), 
       SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 11 THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as SumNov, 
       SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 11 THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as SumDec, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 11 THEN saledate END) as CountNov, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 12 THEN saledate END) as CountDec
FROM trnsact 
WHERE stype = 'p' 
GROUP BY store;
```

Notes:

- `COUNT()` never returns `NULL` so there is no need for the `CASE` at all.
- With an `ELSE` clause, the `SUM()` doesn't return `NULL` either (there would have to be no rows matching for the `SUM()` to return `NULL`, and with no matching rows in the group, the group wouldn't exist).
- `EXTRACT()` returns a number, so compare to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is in your select statement which is not an aggregate like SUM, AVG etc. need to be included in your group by clause if you have a group by clause

Try this hope it helps:

```
SELECT store, COUNT(DISTINCT saledate), CountNov, CountDec, SumNov, SumDec, (SumNov/CountNov) AS NovAvgRvn, (SumDec/CountDec) AS DecAvgRvn FROM 
(
    SELECT store, saledate, 
                CASE WHEN 
                        SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) 
                                WHEN '11' THEN amt END) IS NULL THEN 0 
                            ELSE SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '11' THEN amt END)
                        END AS SumNov, 
                CASE WHEN SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN amt END) IS NULL THEN 0 
                            ELSE SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN amt END)
                        END AS SumDec, 
                CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '11' THEN saledate END) IS NULL THEN 0 
                            ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '11' THEN saledate END)
                        END AS CountNov, 
                CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN saledate END) IS NULL THEN 0 
                            ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN '12' THEN saledate END)
                        END AS CountDec 
    FROM trnsact 
    WHERE stype = 'p' 
    GROUP BY store, saledate, SumNov, SumDec, CountNov, CountDec
) AS T1 
    WHERE CountDec > 0 AND CountNov > 0 
GROUP BY store, saledate, CountNov, CountDec, SumNov, SumDec, NovAvgRvn, DecAvgRvn
ORDER BY store;
```

Comment: Anjani,

Thanks for ur response, but I cannot use CountNov, CountDec, SumNov, SumDec as they are all aggregate functions which make use of sum, coount. So ill try with the NovAvgRvn, DecAvgRvn and see

Comment: But still i'm getting the error, not sure which non aggregate value i'm missing out ???

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` in the Derived Table is not doing aggregation on a month level, thus the `COUNT(DISTINCT saledate)`will be `1`. You shouldn't use strings for numeric data (result of `EXTRACT`). You don't need the `CASE(SUM)` because `COUNT` never returns a NULL (you might use `COALESCE` instead):

I assume you want a query  like this instead:

```
SELECT store, 
   -- if you only need the dates from Nov & Dec you can simply do
   -- CountNov + CountDec instead 
   COUNT(DISTINCT saledate),

   SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 11 THEN amt ELSE 0 END) AS SumNov, 
   SUM(CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 12 THEN amt ELSE 0 END) AS SumDec, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 11 THEN saledate END) AS CountNov, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) WHEN 12 THEN saledate END) AS CountDec, 
   (SumNov/CountNov) AS NovAvgRvn, 
   (SumDec/CountDec) AS DecAvgRvn
FROM trnsact 
WHERE stype = 'p' 
  -- don't you need a condition to filter for a specific year/month?
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) IN (11,12) 
GROUP BY store 
ORDER BY store;
```

Comment: Thnx @dnoeth but the filtering for the specific month, year takes place in the CASE statement itself right ?

Comment: @Vish: You will run the aggregation over all rows in your table when you don't add a `WHERE`-conditon, e.g. if you got one year of data you process 12 instead of 2 months.

Comment: Thank you for your response on this @dnoeth